# Unbound Type Constructor for datatype

Tags: sml, smlnj

if I had initialized a datatype `dataype dd = DAT of int*int`, how do I initialize a type of that for a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type is called `Cint`, not `CI`, so you have to use `Cint` in places where a type is required:

```
fun cadd(a:Cint, b:Cint) =
```

Or you can use a different syntax, involving a pattern, if you want to keep using the datatype constructor `CI`:

```
fun cadd(a as CI _, b as CI _) =
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pattern match directly in the function instead of with a case-of:

```
datatype Cint = CI of int * int

fun get_first_val (CI (a, _)) = a
fun get_second_val (CI (_, b)) = b

fun cadd (CI (a1, b1), CI (a2, b2)) =
  CI (a1+a2, b1+b2)
```